# How to setup particles from CPUParticles3D to collide with a plane/ground

Tags: collision-detection, game-physics, godot, particles

I am creating particles using CPUParticels3D and also defined an Area3D with box shape collision node (refer image below for tree structure).

I want the particles to collide with the area and send signal when it hits the plane so that I can remove them from the system to make it like rain hitting the ground. From the UI, it is not letting me select the particle node as a target to the signal.

Later I am going to create splash on the collision points.

[image: Image shows particle getting pass the collision plane]

[image]